# ASP.Net MVC CSRF Prevention for JSON POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, csrf

I'd like to close the CSRF vulnerability for posting raw JSON via AJAX.

I'm familiar with MVC's mechanism for automating CSRF prevention using the `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute` and `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`; however, if I understand correctly, this mechanism requires that the `POST` be done with a `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (or similar).  Is there a built-in mechanism in ASP.Net MVC that will reject CSRFs for `POST` requests with `Content-Type` of `application/json`?  If not, am I stuck with putting the anti-forgery into the JSON object itself?  Can you recommend a technique for protecting JSON POST requests from CSRF vulnerability with the same level of security as the form-based approach built into ASP.Net MVC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question brings up an interesting discussion.

Provided that the request Content-Type is `application/json`, then CSRF is not a concern.  This is because application/json requests must be submitted via `XmlHttpRequest`, and the cookie which is a necessary part of the verification of your AntiForgeryToken cannot be passed cross-site, but must adhere to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

**However,** it is possible for a malicious user to submit a request via `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which contains the information which will appear to be a valid JSON request, and which will pass any authorization cookies back to your application.  There is a more detailed discussion of this at http://forums.asp.net/t/1624454.aspx/1?MVC3+JSON+Model+binding+not+working+with+AntiForgery and at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7472, where I post a proof-of-concept.

While it is possible to include the __RequestVerificationToken in a JSON request, a better line of defense is to create an Attribute to verify that a request is of type `application/json`, since any other request being submitted to your action which expects JSON is in fact invalid, and should not be handled.

I expect that this security issue will be addressed in MVC 4.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a simple `AuthorizeAttribute` class you can use to decorate any actions which expect to receive JSON:

```
public class JsonRequestAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    /*
     * 
     *   CONFIRM that this is REALLY a JSON request.
     *   This will mitigate the risk of a CSRF attack
     *   which masquerades an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" request
     *   as a JSON request
     * 
     */

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
         if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
         {
             // This request is masquerading as a JSON request, kill it.
             JsonResult unauthorizedResult = new JsonResult();
             unauthorizedResult.Data = "Invalid request";
             unauthorizedResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
             filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
             filterContext.Result = unauthorizedResult;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I now understand why the MVC team didn't implement this.  Is there an attribute in MVC that will validate the Content-Type, or is that an exercise left to the reader? =)

Comment: I updated my answer to include a simple AuthorizeAttribute class

Comment: There is another concern regarding Json request you need to aware, http://bit.ly/jeET7a

Comment: Elegant solution, but it relies on there being no way to spoof the content-type except by using `XmlHttpRequest`. I'm not certain that's a safe assumption to make - the hacker has one common property to spoof and doesn't need any extra application specific information. Instead I think there needs to be a better way to pass the token.

Comment: Confirmed - it is possible to make a request that fools the browser into sending send the user's cookie and a content-type as `application/json` using Flash.

Comment: Be careful with the advice to base your security around `application/json`. it was correct at the time, but may no longer be valid soon. W3C is building a draft that will allow forms to use `application/json` in their enctype attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/ You really should use the Syncrhonizer Token pattern to properly protect against CSRF.

Comment: From the W3C spec the same origin policy is enforced for form posts that use application/json. 

"Given that there exist deployed services using JSON and ambient authentication, and given that form requests are not protected by the same-origin policy by default, if this encoding were left wide open then a number of attacks would become possible. Because of this, when using the application/json form encoding the same-origin policy is enforced."

Comment: This answer is just bad and wrong. There is no inherent protection against the POST of application/json. It will be treated like any other ajax POST that your app makes, which are usually destructive. How does the same origin policy come into play at all? The request isn't submitting any nonce/guid proof of it's origin at all, any request made from an authenticated users browser will include this cookie you refer to, among others (like the users session). If you don't have a specific treatment for ajax style requests your application is vulnerable to those. They're in no way addressed here.